# Rest api, how to avoidmethod for update db with many params

Tags: java, rest, parameter-passing

I have the following method in my resp api

```
@RequestMapping(value = "user", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    @ResponseBody
    public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity> updateUser(@RequestBody Users user, 
    @RequestParam(value = "sid", required = true, defaultValue = "") String sid) throws TimeoutException, SocketTimeoutException {
            //    userController = new UserController(repository);   
            final Integer userId = checkSession(sid);
            final DeferredResult<ResponseEntity> defResult = new DeferredResult<>();
            new Thread(() -> {
                Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new SeparateThreadsExceptionHandler(defResult));
                final String result = userController.validateUserData(userId, user.getName(), user.getSurname(), user.getPhoneCode(), user.getPhoneNumber(), user.getPassword(), user.getEmail(), user.getCarBody(), user.getCarMark(), user.getCarNumber(), sid);
                defResult.setResult(ResponseEntity.ok(result));
            }).start();
            return defResult;
        }
```

The problem is method named `validateUserData`with many params.For example if i change the order of params , the errors will occure later.
In my opinion it would be better to pass object "USER" to "validateUserData" but my menthor said that userController should'nt know about User object therefore my sugestion is not really good.
How did you deal with such problems? I need some best practises.

Comment: It is all up to your mentor's opinion. There is no problem at all. As long as it is "UserController" it makes much more sense to pss to it User object instead of bunch of it's properties. Your suggestion fits to OOP much better. But if your boss-mentor does not like it you have to live with that. :-)